# Where are stored settings of objects?

Tags: swift, xcode

Where are stored settings of `objects` stored? For example if I create a button, where will be its values  `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, `label` be located?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)** and **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40104188/edit) the post to add relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a IBOutlet for the button or any UIElement ,then use the reference to access its properties.

btnObject.frame will gives you x, y, width, height,etc